# AWS SSO + Identity Policy creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

We have SSO (Azure AD) authentication enabled and configured in the organization root account. I am working on a Terraform module in one of the sub-accounts, and the module needs to grant permissions (in this case - ssm:StartSession) on the EC2 instances it creates to a set of SSO users. However, I cannot attach a new policy to the SSO roles of the users, since the roles are created by AWS SSO and cannot be modified directly.

How can I add an identity policy to a specific user/group? I do have access to the root org account, if needed, but I would like a fully automated way of doing so (with Terraform, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I cannot attach a new policy to the SSO roles of the users, since the roles are created by AWS SSO and cannot be modified directly.

Terraform aws provider has resources to attach a managed policy or an inline policy (needed in your use case) to permissions sets:

- [Resource: aws_ssoadmin_managed_policy_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_managed_policy_attachment#example-usage)
- [Resource: aws_ssoadmin_permission_set_inline_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_permission_set_inline_policy)

Permission sets and and inline policies must be created under SSO management account. [Create a new permission set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_permission_set) and inline policy and assign groups with new permissions by using [aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_account_assignment)

You can create multi-account setup for Terraform if you want to deploy resources on multiple accounts. One way to achieve this is described [here](https://thenewstack.io/terraform-on-aws-multi-account-setup-and-other-advanced-tips/).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at those. How would this work from Terraform perspective? Create the resources in the sub-account, and then create the permission set w/ inline policy in the root org? Can Terraform handle multiple accounts for a single provider in the same code?

Comment: @mapa3m Permission sets and inline policies must be created under SSO management account. I tested some of the sso-admin commands with AWS CLI and they were denied if used with a profile nort linked to management account.  Similarly, you are not able to modify anything if logged in to sub-account by using AWS Console.